# Show field collection fields with profile field

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have used Recruiter module to manage job and resume and its working almost well but when i m displaying resumes it has field collection like Personal information which contain some field like name, address etc. and some normal fields. Now i want to show all of them in table.I tried field collection views but its showing all field collection data in single column called personal information with other fields.

Please let me know how i can do this....really struggling in drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading it correctly, you should be able to create a relationship based on your Field Collection field.

Under Advanced (this might be collapsed in the Views UI - it normally is by default) click relationship, and then click on the Field Collection field containing your user information.

Now you'll find when you go to add a field into your Views display, that there are more fields available to you.  These are the fields stored in the Field Collection entity that you can now style in a table, an accordion, a list...whatever you fancy!